Chain rule for matrix derivative
Say if I have a matrix $\mathbf{X}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times3}$, and another matirx $\mathbf{Y}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times3}$, where $n<N$. The relation of these two matrices is defined as $\mathbf{Y}=\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{X})\mathbf{X}$, where $\mathcal{S}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times N}$ is a matrix defined using information from $\mathbf{X}$.
Let $l$ be a scalar, and I already have $\frac{dl}{d\mathbf{Y}}$. Now I need to apply the chain rule to calculate $\frac{dl}{d\mathbf{X}}$. However, I am not sure the following chain rule formula is correct:
$$
\frac{dl}{d\mathbf{X}}=\frac{dl}{d\mathbf{Y}}\frac{d\mathbf{Y}}{d\mathbf{X}}=\frac{dl}{d\mathbf{Y}}\left(\frac{d\mathcal{S}}{d\mathbf{X}}\mathbf{X}+\mathcal{S}\right)
$$
I realize the dimension was not correct: $dl/d\mathbf{Y}$ should be $n\times3$, but $\mathcal{S}$ has shape $n\times N$, they cannot be multiplied.
What is the proper chain rule?

Is it a differentiable function of the entires?

yes, it is a differentiable function of entries

$
\def\l{\ell}
\def\H{{\cal H}}
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\g#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\GLR#1{\g{\LR{#1}}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\Si{\sum_{i=1}^m}
\def\Sk{\sum_{k=1}^m}
\def\Sj{\sum_{j=1}^n}
\def\Sl{\sum_{l=1}^n}
$Let's use a colon to denote the double-contraction product.
When applied to matrices $\{A,B,X,Y\}\,$, it has the following properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \Si\Sj A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
B:B &= \frob{B}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{XY}:B &= X:\LR{BY^T} \;=\; Y:\LR{X^TB} \\
}$$
When applied to vectors, it reduces to the standard dot product.
It can also be applied to higher-order tensors.
For example, given a fourth-order tensor $\H$
$$\eqalign{
A:\H &= \Si\Sj A_{ij}\H_{ijkl} \\
\H:B &= \Sk\Sl \H_{ijkl}B_{kl} \\\\
}$$

In the current problem we're given the following information
$$\eqalign{
Y &= SX &\qiq \c{dY = \LR{S\,dX+dS\,X}} \\
\H &= \grad SX &\qiq \g{dS = \H:dX} \\
G &= \grad{\l}Y &\qiq d\l = G:dY \\
}$$
Take the differential of $\l$ and change the independent variable
from $Y\to X$
$$\eqalign{
d\l &= G:\c{dY} \\
 &= G:\CLR{S\,dX+dS\,X} \\
 &= \LR{S^TG}:dX \;+\; \LR{GX^T}:\g{dS} \\
 &= \LR{S^TG}:dX \;+\; \LR{GX^T}:\g{\H:dX} \\
\grad{\l}{X}
 &= \;S^TG \,\;+\; \LR{GX^T}:\H \\
}$$

In index form the chain rule is written as
$$\left(\dfrac{\mathrm d l}{\mathrm d\mathbf X}\right)_{ij}=\dfrac{\mathrm d l}{\mathrm dX_{ji}}=\dfrac{\mathrm d l}{\mathrm d Y_{k\ell}}\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm d Y_{\ell k}}{\mathrm d X_{ji}},\ i=1...N,\ j=1...3,\ k=1...3,\ \ell=1...n$$
We can further simplify by introducing $\mathbf Y=\mathcal S\mathbf X$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\left(\dfrac{\mathrm d l}{\mathrm d\mathbf X}\right)_{ij}=\dfrac{\mathrm d l}{\mathrm dX_{ji}}&=\dfrac{\mathrm d l}{\mathrm d Y_{k\ell}}\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d X_{ji}}(\mathcal S_{\ell m}X_{mk})\\
&=\dfrac{\mathrm d l}{\mathrm d Y_{k\ell}}\cdot\left(\dfrac{\mathrm d \mathcal S_{\ell m}}{\mathrm d X_{ji}}X_{mk}+S_{\ell m}\delta_{mj}\delta_{ki}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{\mathrm d l}{\mathrm d Y_{k\ell}}\cdot\left(\dfrac{\mathrm d \mathcal S_{\ell m}}{\mathrm d X_{ji}}X_{mk}+S_{\ell j}\delta_{ki}\right)
\end{aligned}$$
I don't really know how to express this in matrix notation since the terms in the parentheses are $4$th order tensors.
